# Help with field calculator in Python script

Tags: python, arcmap, field-calculator, arcgis-10.2

I am getting a syntax error in my script but I know from testing it in ArcMap attribute table, the syntax is fine. Anyone have any idea why this code doesn't work? I see that a search cursor has been used in this situation but (a) I'm not familiar with them and (b) why wont the way I'm doing it work?

EDIT* - I have added an alternate working codeblock to the script below. Seems both ways work just fine!

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

#Path of the workspace
in_workspace = r"C:\folder"

fieldName = "Symbology"

expression = "Class(!City!)"
```

This is also another way that it works. So both work just fine. Thanks again for all the help!

```
code ='''
def Class(City):
    if 'Milwaukee' in City:
        return 2
    elif 'Kenosha' in City:
        return 4
    elif 'Madison' in City:
        return 9
    else:
        return 0
'''

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(in_workspace, datatype="FeatureClass",type="All"):
    if "skipFolder" in dirnames:
        dirnames.remove('skipFolder')   
    for filename in filenames:
        if "City" in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))]:
            arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(dirpath,filename), fieldName, "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE")
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(os.path.join(dirpath,filename), "Symbology", expression, "PYTHON", code)
        else:
            print "no City field for dataset ", filename

#Prints text that shows script has finished running
print "message that reflected field calc use"
print "Finished script"
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the field calculator in the field `"Symbology"`? Or is it rather the field `"City"`?

Comment: Yes, I want to use it in "Symbology". The idea is that I can control how to symbolize with a numeric value instead of using the actual city field while maintaining the "City" field values. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to substitute the `code` variable with this:

```
code ='''
def Class(City):
    if City == 'Milwaukee':
        return 1
    elif City == 'Kenosha':
        return 2
    else:
        return 5
'''
```

Comment: This worked! My only question is why? Any insight on why it works this way and not the other? Very happy though thank you very much. Cheers!

Comment: Glad that it worked. It's only a way to keep more readable and clean the code. However there was an `elif` missing, so all ones became fives.

Comment: So strange that it worked with no issues on a merged version of the dataset with no issues (using the original codeblock) inside of the attribute table. Funny I tried City = 'Milwaukee' with no luck, guess I have much to learn! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @afalciano & ustroetz I fixed the above code with an alternate example that works just as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @ustroetz `in` works for string variables too: `'Kenosha' in 'Where is Kenosha?'` is True

Comment: @MikeToews Oh, didn't know that. Thanks!